# One Line of Swift code works one day and doesn't the next (Only Xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Very simply I need to get the power of an Integer and I have this code to do so below

```
import Darwin

var x = Int(pow(Double(3),Double(3)))
print(x)
```

For whatever reason this line of code worked one day and the next day when I came back to the project it did not work and instead of getting 27 I keep getting 3...?

What confuses me more is if I go into Swift Playgrounds(The App) it works fine but put it in Xcode and it doesn't work.  I haven't changed the code at all and are just copy/paste into different programs with different results

Comment: Are you sure that there is no function `pow` defined in your program that is hiding the Swift Library one?

Comment: Related? https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/qz6rzy/how_does_the_pow_function_work/

Comment: Try `Darwin.pow(...)`

Comment: Well I have tried the ```Dawrin.pow(...)``` and I just keep getting 3.0 but whats making it werid this problem only occurs in xcode I am just getting more confused